# How to capture an image and store on server using android 

Tags: android, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image from an Android device to a remote server. So far I have the following code but the image being saved on the remote server is always zero bytes.

```
     HttpURLConnection conn;

     String serverpath = "http://110.172.27.47:9499";
     String MREPORTER_SERVLET_PATH="/mreporter/servlet/MReporterServlet";


     url = serverpath + MREPORTER_SERVLET_PATH;

     try
     {
         URL url = new URL( serverpath + MREPORTER_SERVLET_PATH );
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         conn.setUseCaches(false);

         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); 
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+ "*****" );

         conn.setRequestProperty(USER_NAME_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "parth");
         conn.setRequestProperty(EVENT_NAME_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "null" );
         conn.setRequestProperty(CAMERAID_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "1");
         conn.setRequestProperty(ACTION_MODE_PARAMETER, "POST_DATA_ACTION" );

         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         Log.i("Response", conn.getResponseCode() + "" );

         int response = conn.getResponseCode();

         if ( response == 200 )
         {
             Log.i("size",data.length + "");

             if ( data.length > 0 )
             {
                 dos.write(data);
                 Log.i("200","OK" );
             }
             else
             {
                 Log.i( "Error", response +  "" );
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I review thw code and get the solution here it works surely.

```
     HttpURLConnection conn;
     String serverpath = "http://110.172.27.47:9499";
     String MREPORTER_SERVLET_PATH="/mreporter/servlet/MReporterServlet";


     url = serverpath + MREPORTER_SERVLET_PATH;

     try
     {
         URL url = new URL( serverpath + MREPORTER_SERVLET_PATH );
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         conn.setUseCaches(false);

         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); 
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+ "*****" );

         conn.setRequestProperty(USER_NAME_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "parth");
         conn.setRequestProperty(EVENT_NAME_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "null" );
         conn.setRequestProperty(CAMERAID_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "1");
         conn.setRequestProperty(ACTION_MODE_PARAMETER, "POST_DATA_ACTION" );

         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         Log.i("Response", conn.getResponseCode() + "" );

         int response = conn.getResponseCode();
         dos.write(data);
}
```

Comment: Don't put you answer as an comment give a proper specification(If you know well) so it can be useful to other also

Answer (score 0):

I think this [example](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/) can help you out.